# ASP.NET MVC Routing & Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my routes file I have this setup:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Stages", // Route name
            url: "Stages/{action}", // URL with parameters
            defaults: new { controller = "Tasks", action = "Index", taskTypeIds = new[] { TaskTypes.Stage } }
);

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The problem now is that I want to define two main menu items:

```
                <li>@Html.RouteLink("Stages", "Stages")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tasks", "Index", "Tasks")</li>
```

But what this outputs for both is the same URL:

/Stages

Why is it doing this, and can I get around it?

Comment: What you are expecting in the both cases?

Comment: What outputs are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting:

/Tasks and
/Stages

Respectively.

Comment: Are you saying that `@Html.ActionLink("Tasks", "Index", "Tasks")` actually outputs a link to `/Stages`?

Comment: I am! Yes. I'm not too sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is Task for stages route.

Comment: I think i did. You mentioned URL - Stages for controller Task. See the maproute once again for name: "Stages".